# Display optgroup label as initial option

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to show the label of an optgroup in a select dropdown as the first option?

Does this make sense? Or is there a better way to do it?

I basically need a first label that shows like Select Price and that isn't directly selectable, but shows when you expand the select menu like an optgroup label does.

Comment: You could use javascript to move a given optgroup to the top of the list

Comment: This question is a good question, not sure why it's marked as not constructive? It's a question that has an answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a standard `option` element and simply specify the `disabled` attribute:

```html
<select>
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Price</option>
  <optgroup label="Gold">
    <option>5.00</option>
    <option>10.00</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

See this [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgCG7/).

Comment: thanks very much, i guess this looks like the way to go, an annoying problem!

Comment: Even better, you can add hidden="hidden" so it wont show in the list but still be visible at first