# Use optgroup label as default option in select element

Tags: html, select, optgroup

I use a `<select>` on my page and have set an `<optgroup>` with a label (Language options). I'd like the value of the select to be the optgroup label by default instead of the text of the first `<option>` within it (***EN***, FR, SP,...).

Is there another way in HTML5 to set the default value of a `<select>`?

EDIT: maybe a disabled first option with the title will work.

Comment: that's what I meant, sorry, corrected it. thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display optgroup label as initial option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224466/display-optgroup-label-as-initial-option)