# How to prepend the <optgroup> text to the selected <option> text on a <select> dropdown when it isn't in focus?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I display the text from the selected `<option>`'s `<optgroup>` on the dropdown when it is not in focus?

Currently it looks like this when *not* in focus:

[image]

When it is in focus it looks like this:

[image]

If possible I'd like it to show "Hepatitis B - Core antibody blood test" when it is not in focus.

Is there any way to do this?

The code currently looks something like this:

```
<select name="bloodsVaccinesTypesBloods-${newRowId}" id="bloodsVaccinesTypesBloods-${newRowId}" class="bloodsVaccinesDropdown bloodsVaccinesTestTypes bloodsVaccinesTypesBloods">
    <optgroup label="Hepatitis B">
        <option value="12" selected="selected">Antigen blood test</option>
        <option value="13">Core antibody blood test</option>
        <option value="10">Vaccine (course of 3 vaccines & 5 year booster)</option>
    <optgroup label="Hepatitis C">
        <option value="14">Antibody blood test</option>
        <option value="15">RNA blood test</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224526/1371131

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804432/1371131

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making optgroup label as selected in dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860855/making-optgroup-label-as-selected-in-dropdown)

Comment: @weltschmerz Thanks for taking the time to look at this. They're great starting points but they make the first `<optgroup>` the one that is shown when it is not in focus (maybe only until one is clicked also?)... but I'm hoping to show *both* the `<optgroup>` text and *also* the `<option>` text. For this reason the question is **not a duplicate**. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Maybe I could make a fake `<option>` triggered on an `onchange` if there isn't a cleaner way to do it...

Comment: You could use the option 'label' attribute and use jquery to get the text from the optgroup and prepend to it

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick (Note I've assumed id=bloodsVaccinesTypesBloods):

```
$('#bloodsVaccinesTypesBloods').focusout(function(){
      $('#bloodsVaccinesTypesBloods > optgroup').each(function() {
         $(this).children().each(function() {
         $(this).attr('label',$(this).parent().attr('label')+ ' - ' + $(this).text());
      });
      });
});

$('#bloodsVaccinesTypesBloods').focus(function(){
       $('#bloodsVaccinesTypesBloods > optgroup').each(function() {
                    $(this).children().each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('label',$(this).text());
                     });
                });
});
```

i.e. https://jsfiddle.net/hzg684d3/

Comment: Was this of any use to you ?